# Addition of fractions in C: Floating point exception

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm writing a little program working with fractions:

```
struct fraction
{
     int num;
     int den;
};

typedef struct fraction FRAC;
```

I use a least common multiple function to add two fractions (without simpilfying them afterwards):

```
FRAC *add (FRAC a, FRAC b)
{
    int l = lcm(a.den, b.den);
    FRAC *sum;
    sum = malloc(sizeof(FRAC));
    sum->den = l;
    int la = l/a.den;
    int lb = l/b.den;
    sum->num = a.num*la + b.num*lb;
    return sum;
}
```

Given an array of `FRAC` I want to calculate the sum with following function:

```
FRAC* fraction_sum (FRAC *a, unsigned int size)
{
    int i;
    FRAC* sum = malloc(sizeof(FRAC));
    sum->num = 0;
    sum->den = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        FRAC b = {sum->num, sum->den};
        sum = add(b,a[i]);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

However this expression

```
print(*fraction_sum(fractions, N));
```

returns the error

```
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Any ideas? Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps your initial denominator should be 1? Right now your initial fraction is 0/0... 0/1 would make more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like You are dividing by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Change your initialisation to

```
   sum->den = 1;
```

Comment: Initializing both numerator and denominator will give the wrong sum.

Answer (score 0):

You are **dividing by zero**.

The first time u call function add, the parameter *a* has both its *num* and *den* equal to zero.
This causes that exception you are getting later in this expression.

```
int la = l/a.den;
```

Initializing b.den to 1 should stop your program from crashing.
But it may not produce the correct sum I'm afraid.